# Error: Request failed with status code 400 in react-native with axios

Tags: react-native

```
axios({
method: 'POST',
url: `http://${base_url}/token`,
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
},
data: {
"Username": "admin@diginepal.com",
"Password": "password@123456",
"grant_type": "password"
}
})
.then(res => {
console.log(res)
})
.catch(err => {
console.log(err)
})
```

I'm getting err: request failed with status code 400. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the error is likely on your backend, so if you didnt provide your backend code here, people wont be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Good that you managed to solve, for future reference, if you have a 400 Bad Request error, i found really useful to print the error.response.data for more meaningful error messages.

```
axios.post('/').then(response => {
     console.log(response.data);
 }).catch(error => {
     console.log(error.response.data);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: qs.stringify({
"Username": "admin@diginepal.com",
"Password": "password@123456",
"grant_type": "password"
})


headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
        },
```

using qs and changing the headers solved my problem.